# Angular Material 2 Table get Data From Server

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material2

I am trying to get data from server in Angular Material 2 Application but i am doing something wrong somewhere maybe it is not loading data from server. this is not loading my data into table.

userComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent {
    displayedColumns = ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email'];
    dataSource: UserDataSource;

    constructor(private userSrvc: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.userSrvc);
    }

    logPage(length) {
        console.log(length);
    }
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<User> {
    userSrvc: any;
    length = 20;
    data: Observable<User[]>;

    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    constructor(userService) {
        super();
        this.userSrvc = userService;
    }

    connect(): Observable<User[]> {

      this.userSrvc.get().subscribe(users => {
          this.data = users;
      })
      return this.data;
    }

    disconnect() { }
}
```

if i try to return inside the connect method it give me error in console log.

here is my **UserService.ts** where i am calling user api for getting data.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  get(): Observable<User[]> {
    let header: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
    return this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}user/get/`, options)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return <User[]>response.json();
      }).catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

  errorHandler(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(`Error Message: ${error.statusText}`);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted my code here for Material data table with Firebase.  Should mostly help with your situation.  It is tricky to figure out.

[Angular Material 2 Data Table Connect to AngularFire2 or Firebase Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336706/angular-material-2-data-table-connect-to-angularfire2-or-firebase-service)